# Escaping quotes in a PHP script using ssh2_exec

Tags: php, ssh, gnu-screen, libssh2

I need some help with escaping the quotes in this script, I have code above and below, but it does not pertain to this because if I just issue a screen -d -m -S minecraft, it creates one fine. Any help would be amazing because i've been trying for an hour now, Thanks!

```
 if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, 'screen -d -m -S minecraft -p 0 -X stuff "\printf "\say This is a test.\r"\"\' ))) {
        echo "fail: unable to execute command\n";
    } else {
        // collect returning data from command
        stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
        $data = "";
        while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)) {
            $data .= $buf;
        }
        echo $data;
        fclose($stream);
    }
```

Comment: If you aren't using a text editor with syntax highlighting yet, this is the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the `\` should go before the `"`. Also, from your description, it sounds like that you only want to run "screen -d -m -S minecraft" and it looks like you have an extra printf in there.

```
if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "screen -d -m -S minecraft")))
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you! That worked, kinda? It atleast runs my php script now, but returns me the following error: No screen session found.

Comment: I want to send a command to the screen when I first create it, something simple like "free -m" to find out if it works first would be great, because it's not working for me

Comment: That sounds like the ssh connection worked but screen is giving you an error back. Are you sure your arguments are correct. Can you try adding "-p 0 -X" at the end of the string to see if that changes anything?

Comment: You can send another command by running ssh2_exec again. So you can try running ssh2_exec($con, "free -m") afterwards, but that sounds like a different issue to the string escaping question.

Comment: When I added just "-p 0 -X" to the end it said Please specify a command. I want to be able to create a screen and execute a command to it right away, and then later be able to access the screen and send commands to it also

Comment: I'm not a screen expert but looking at the usage, isn't the command (i.e. start top) "screen -d -m -S mysession top" and then to resume you can run "screen -R mysession". Where mysession is a friendly name that you give for the session.

Comment: So that worked! With just the top but when I tried to do a command with an argument "free -m" it did not create the session

Comment: Try "screen -d -m -S mysession \"free -m\""

Comment: Hmmm didnt seem to do anything, I did:   if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "screen -d -m -S mysession \"free -m\"" ))) {

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change `"\` to `\"`.